# HIVE select count(*) non null returns higher value than select count(*)

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hive-configuration

I am currently doing some data exploration with Hive and cannot explain the following behavior. Say I have a table (named mytable) with a field master_id.

When I count the number of row I get

```
select count(*) as c from mytable 
c
1129563
```

If I want to count the number of row with a non null master_id, I get a higher number

```
select count(*) as c from mytable where master_id is not null
c
1134041
```

Additionally, the master_id seems to be never null.

```
select count(*) as c from mytable where master_id is null
c
0
```

I cannot explain how adding a where statement can increase the number of rows eventually. Does anyone have any hint to explain this behavior ?

Thanks

Comment: What does the schema of that table look like?

Comment: provide your table schema

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most probably your query without where is using statistics because of this parameter is set:

```
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
```

Try to set it false and execute again.

Alternatively you can compute statistics on the table. 
See [ANALYZE TABLE SYNTAX](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev#StatsDev-ExistingTables%E2%80%93ANALYZE)

Also it's possible to gather statistics during INSERT OVERWRITE automatically:

```
set hive.stats.autogather=true;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed if I set hive.compute.query.using.stats to false, both counts match.

Comment: This is something new to analyze.. Good one.