# hive select count(*) data displaying, but no data visible

Tags: hive, hiveql

I see when I run query select count(*) from table; there's a count of data displaying. but when I check select * from table; there no data been displaying.

can you please help these are external table I went to the location of the tables and I see there's no data present.

Comment: Clarify "count of data displaying". 0?

Comment: "count of data displaying"- 45668, Select * from table; not data diaplying

Comment: Please see also this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39914232/2700344

Answer (score 2):

run  `analyze table table_name COMPUTE STATISTICS ;` on your table.
This will give correct result. As COLUMN_STATS (count) of the table in hive is indexed for fast retrieval. Hence after deleting the underlying data/file , it will give the old stats.