# Number of rows does not match

Tags: sql, hive

My query

```
insert into table hist
Select subs2.SUBS_KEY
, subs2.FACT_DATE
, subs2.TYPE
, subs2.BALANCE
, '${DATE_1D}' as TIME_KEY
from subs2
where CNT < 15 and AMT > 0;
```

where `'${DATE_1D}'` is `hivevar DATE_1D=2017-02-28`

after it is executed number of rows goes from

```
db.hist stats: [numFiles=22168, numRows=254582570, totalSize=19188669803, rawDataSize=19613070967]
```

to

```
db.hist stats: [numFiles=22268, numRows=257376901, totalSize=19386949977, rawDataSize=19808556810]
```

difference = 2794331 rows

But when I do

```
insert into table db.new_hist
select *
from db.hist
where time_key = '2017-02-28';
```

I get

```
db.new_hist stats: [numFiles=201, numRows=178798, totalSize=2227208, rawDataSize=12510497]
```

I created `new_hist` using `create table like`

result of show create

```
CREATE TABLE `db.hist`(
  `subs_key` string,
  `fact_date` string,
  `type` int,
  `balance` double,
  `time_key` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

Why does the number of rows not match?

I did a

```
Select count(*)
from hist
```

with and without

```
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
```

result in both cases = 246210052

for some reason logs for insert showed the wrong number of rows.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Check statistics configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39914232/2700344

Comment: If you insist on storing date/time values as strings you will suffer the consequences. Check your assumptions there and check for triggers.