# Select count(*) issue with hive and spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I get the correct count after I run the ANALYZE statement. 
But my problem is, it needs to be run every time of the count is updated. Technically I should be able to update the count for the same partition.

But it returns the same count if I don't execute the ANALYZE statement.

This is the query I execute for the count to be updated.

```
ANALYZE TABLE bi_events_identification_carrier_sam PARTITION(year, month, day) COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

And executing is not convenient at all. any ideas?

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914232/2700344. You can do autogather during insert overwrite or switch-off statistics usage and table will be scanned each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HIVE select count(\*) non null returns higher value than select count(\*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912784/hive-select-count-non-null-returns-higher-value-than-select-count)

Comment: `count(*)` is broken in Hive **by design** since V0.14 -- consistent with Facebook motto _"fail fast, fail all the time, fail big"_ > seriously, you can use a trick like `where X is null` when you know that column X is never null (but the SQL optimizer does not)

Comment: @Sam What engine are you using to write data - spark/hive?

Answer (score 2):

Your count(*) query is using stats to get the result.

If you are using *spark* to write data, then you can set `spark.sql.statistics.size.autoUpdate.enabled` to `true`. This makes sure that Spark updates the table stats automatically after the write is done.

If you are using Hive, you can set `set hive.stats.autogather=true;`.

Once you enable these settings, then the write query will automatically update the stats and the subsequent read query will work fine.

Comment: I didnt worked. Its giving the same result and only works if I again use the ANALYZE statement.  
and im writing from spark.