# hive select count(*) from table has one more row than select * from table

Tags: hive, hbase

I have 2 hive table,first table is hive on hbase,second table is a hive table,
I insert second table from first table(hive on hbase),but when I run:

```sql
select count(*) from table
```

I got different row number,but when I run:

```sql
select * from table
```

they have same number data, I am so confused about that.

Comment: This maybe an issue with statistics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914232/2700344

Comment: I set hive.compute.query.using.stats=false but it not working

Comment: You can try also this one: set hive.stats.autogather=true; then recreate table and try again.

Comment: I found  Hbase has 100 rows,I run select count(*) from table(hive on hbase) also has 100 rows,but when I run select * from table(hive on hbase) only has 99 rows