# Must run "analyze table" in hive else count(*) shows 0

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, parquet

I am creating an external Hive table on a parquet file on S3.  The commands look like

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE userinfo(
  user_id string,
  last_name string,
  first_name string
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  yr string,
  mo string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mybucket/basedir/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.null.format'='');

alter table userinfo add IF NOT EXISTS partition (yr='2021', mo='07');
```

At this point, if I run "select count(*) from userinfo", I get 0 as the result.  But if I then run

```
ANALYZE TABLE userinfo PARTITION(yr='2021', mo='07') COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

and rerun the "select count(*)..." I get the expected row count.

This isn't a show-stopper, but it makes me think I'm doing something/failing to do something that's causing this strange behavior.  Any insights are welcome.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914232/2700344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling optimizer the statistics of the table so it shows 0 because it doesnt know anything about the data in it.
Ideally you should gather statistics whenever you load data into a table/partition.  Stale statistics or no statistics will keep optimizer thinking/guessing and thus making queries run longer/consume more memory and sometime return wrong values.
Now, you can setup this property in hive for auto stats gathering -

```
hive.stats.autogather=true
```

Or you can gather them manually right after loading data into it.

```
ANALYZE TABLE tab COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```