# Why is the sum function not working properly in HIVE?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table in HIVE that when I sum the columns for Value1, it gives me an incorrect value.

```
ID, VALUE1
1   10
1   -100
1   10
1   20
1   -60
1  110
1   10
```

When you sum all these values, you should get '0'. However, the query in HIVE when I use sum(value1) is giving me '-20', which is what you get if you were to add them all in order.

VALUE1 is INT.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the type of column VALUE1?

Comment: Hello, it is INT

Comment: Possible issue with statistics used for query calculation https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914232/2700344